# Retrieve the text image value of a table from sysobject?

Tags: sql-server

Working on creating a dynamic table script process which should include text image on also in the script so that it will be created in respective file group.

If it is not mentioned then it creates textimage on in default filegroup in the destination environment
which property in sysobject needs to be checked?

Is there a way to get the list of tables in a database that has text image on in SQL server 2016?

Comment: Whats have your tried?

Comment: if table has column with data types (text, ntext, image, xml, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and CLR user-defined type columns) then     we can specify the file group to store the corresponding column data , if nothing specified then data for that column will be stored in  default filegroup.                                                i want to know whether there is column in sys object or information schema tables to identify this directly and get the list of all tables in database.